# Active Admin: how to apply search filter while typing in active_admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model product in which i want to filter it with it's user and I have used this code

```
 filter :product_type_user_id_eq, as: :select, collection: -> {
    User.all.map { |user| [user.name, user.id] }
  }, label: 'User'
```

I have thousands of users so when I use the above code it takes time to load all the users.
Is there any way that I can apply a search filter while typing. so the first step, loading all users can be eliminated and when I type something in the search filter it gives data users according to that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correct, but if your are searching for som attributes on users, you could try something like Stimulus Reflex. They have a nifty example of a use case that might suite you.

https://expo.stimulusreflex.com/demos/tabular

here you can cain your attributes

Make sure to index your query fields, for better performance

Comment: Thanks for response but i need to do by using active-admin gem

Answer (score 0):

There are some Selectize based plugins that may help, eg. [ActiveAdmin::AjaxFilter](https://github.com/holyketzer/activeadmin-ajax_filter). See the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins#selects) for others.

Answer (score 0):

Use a select2 input with the ActiveAdmin addons gem:

https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons#select2-input

And for select2 use the ajax option:

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax